# Overlapping or wrongly aligned struct

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling

I have an issue with my struct layout. I want to have a struct with an array of other structs. The compiler does not complain with my implementation:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 8)]
public struct block
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int x;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int y;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 84)]
public struct tower
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int x;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    public block[] blocks;
};
```

When I run my program it throws an exception with the following message:

> System.TypeLoadException
> HResult=0x80131522
> Message=Could not load type 'tower' from assembly 'F1_Voice, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 4 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.
> Source=F1_Voice
> StackTrace:
> at F1_Voice.Program.UDP() in C:\Users\meule\source\repos\F1_Voice\Program.cs:line 28
> at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback() in /_/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Thread.CoreCLR.cs:line 106

I can not figure out what is wrong. I have tried many variations but none have worked so far.

Edit 1:

Okay it works if I change my code to this (if I understood Marc correctly it should be aligned at 8):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 88)]
public struct tower
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int x;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    public block[] blocks;
};
```

But I fail to understand why it works. Since an int is 4 bytes right? so x starting from 0 to 3 and then the array starting from 4 to ....

To answer the question of Marc, I would like it to be a fixed array. Since the data coming in (that will be serialized) always contains the same number of elements.

Comment: is this x64? since `block[]` is an array (not a fixed buffer), it would need to be aligned at 8, no? but: should this actually be a fixed buffer? or an inline array?

Comment: re your edit: "fixed arrays" aren't a thing; there are "fixed size buffers", but that requires pre-defined primitives; however, a new .NET 8 feature "inline arrays" does *exactly this*

Comment: if you can't use .NET 8, another option is to simply allocate the space and *wave a wand to make it work* - I can give an example of that, too

Comment: as a separate observation: I regularly see people using `struct` for inappropriate things; can I ask *what you are doing here* that requires explicit layout? if you *actually have a reason*, fine: but I wonder if if this is another example of "because". In particular, the fact that the `struct`s are not `readonly` and have `public` fields makes me very suspicious.

Comment: @MarcGravell I am working on a project where I receive a serialized byte array from another device over UDP. I need to deserialize it into its previous format. The way it was stored is specified, and it is indicated that structs were used to store the data. All that is left for me is to deserialize the byte array back into the previous specified struct. I then want to access the variables in the struct to analyze them

Comment: right; in that case: note that you can thunk/pun/coerce (whatever you want to call it) between `Span<byte>` and `Span<tower>` (using `MemoryMarshal.Cast`) to do this very efficiently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, the problem here is that `public block[] blocks;` is not part of the same struct - that field is a *reference* to an entirely separate array, and *does not* represent the rest of that same chunk of memory. References need to be word aligned, and on x64 the word size is 8, not 4 - hence the problem.

However, fixing the alignment to 8 doesn't solve the real problem, as we'd still be talking about unrelated memory, and your deserialize step won't work as intended.

---

This is a perfect candidate for the new "inline array" feature in .NET 8; this allows a custom type to *look* like a regular `struct`, while actually being refactored (via the runtime and compiler combined) into something that behaves sort of like an array - similar to "fixed size buffers", but for custom types; example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

var obj = new tower();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    obj.Blocks[i] = new Block { x = i, y = -i };
}
foreach (var block in obj.Blocks)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{block.x} {block.y}");
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 8)]
public struct Block
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int x;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int y;
}

[InlineArray(10)] // lots of magic happening here
public struct Block10
{
    private Block _element0;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 84)]
public struct tower
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int x;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public Block10 Blocks;
};
```

---

If .NET 8 isn't an option, you can just allocate the space via `Size`, and *wave a magic wand* to access the data:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

var obj = new tower();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    obj[i] = new Block { x = i, y = -i };
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var block = obj[i];
    Console.WriteLine($"{block.x} {block.y}");
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 8)]
public struct Block
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int x;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int y;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1, Size = 84)]
public struct tower
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int x;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    private Block _block0; // use Unsafe.Add to access the rest

    public Block this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= 10) ThrowIndexOutOfRange();
            return Unsafe.Add(ref _block0, index);
        }
        set
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= 10) ThrowIndexOutOfRange();
            Unsafe.Add(ref _block0, index) = value;
        }
    }
    private static void ThrowIndexOutOfRange()
        => throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("index");
};
```